# Tracking Word from xls file unity vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xls, vuforia

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to import data from a xls file into
Unity, and use this with vuforia and c# scripting to be able to track words from the xls file and display there corresponding values from the spread sheet.

I could simply copy the words into a white list to be able to track them, but then how would I go about using this to display each rows information.

To clarify slightly, I have a spreadsheet of car names and there sale prices and mileage. I would want to track the car name and be able to display the price and mileage on screen.

Any point in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel allows you to save the file as a .csv file instead of .xls. If you can use this, you could use the [CSVReader from Unify](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSVReader) in order to import your data.
If you want to keep the .xls, you could try [Unity Quick-sheet](https://github.com/kimsama/Unity-QuickSheet), I didn't try it myself.

Once the data are loaded, you can store them in a simple structure and build a List or a Dict out of it, depending on the requirement.

I have never used Vuforia so I won't be able to help you there.